# Laravel options on event listener aren't being used

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in a Laravel 10 project and have an event/listener set up. My event, called `UptimeHourlySummaryStatCreation` is dispatched via one of my Laravel jobs. Traditionally, with a Laravel job, if I set the `failed` method in the code then rather than the job going into `failed_jobs` table it goes into the method.

My event listener isn't preferring this despite it being set, in addition, I've set the maximum number of `tries` on my listener to 1, but in the database I see it re-attempting 3 times before it fails, what's going on here?

Am I missing something obvious that's stopping both `tries` and `failed` from being used?

Here's my event:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UptimeHourlySummaryStatCreation
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        public mixed $lastCheckedAt,
        public int $userId,
        public int $monitorId,
        public int $totalResponseDuration = 0,
        public int $totalChecksPerformed = 1,
        public int $totalSuccessfulChecksPerformed = 0,
        public int $totalFailedChecksPerformed = 0
    ) {}

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('channel-name'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Here's my listener:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\UptimeHourlySummaryStatCreation;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use App\Models\UptimeHourlySummaryStat;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Throwable;

class StoreUptimeHourlySummaryStat implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * The name of the connection the job should be sent to.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $connection = 'database-short-running';

    /**
     * The name of the queue the job should be sent to.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $queue = 'statistics-hourly';

    /**
     * The number of times the queued listener may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 1;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(UptimeHourlySummaryStatCreation $event): void
    {
        $statistic = UptimeHourlySummaryStat::firstOrCreate([
            'user_id' => $event->userId,
            'monitor_id' => $event->monitorId,
            'grouped_at' => Carbon::parse($event->lastCheckedAt)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')
        ]);

        // set count of each check
        $statistic->total_checks_performed = $statistic->total_checks_performed + $event->totalChecksPerformed;
        $statistic->total_successful_checks_performed = $statistic->total_successful_checks_performed + $event->totalSuccessfulChecksPerformed;
        $statistic->total_failed_checks_performed = $statistic->total_failed_checks_performed + $event->totalFailedChecksPerformed;

        // set the response durations
        $statistic->total_response_duration = $statistic->total_response_duration + $event->totalResponseDuration;

        if (!$statistic->total_checks_performed) {
            $statistic->avg_response_duration = 0;
        } else {
            $statistic->avg_response_duration = round($statistic->total_response_duration / $statistic->total_checks_performed);
        }

        // set checked date and save
        $statistic->last_checked_at = Carbon::parse($event->lastCheckedAt);
        $statistic->save();
    }

    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     */
    public function failed(UptimeHourlySummaryStatCreation $event, Throwable $exception): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If it's of use, here's my config for my queues:

```
// for short running queues
'database-short-running' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'short-running',
    'retry_after' => 80,
    'after_commit' => false,
],

'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 90,
    'after_commit' => false,
],

// for long running queues
'database-long-running' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'long-running',
    'retry_after' => 300,
    'after_commit' => false,
],
```

Comment: Add $maxExceptions = 1 ... Also check laravel log to see if any errors happens? ... Add logger in the cycle to see if failed method is working or breaks somewhere

Comment: I don't think `maxExceptions` is supported by a queued laravel listener? My problem here is that the options I'm setting just aren't being used for some reason despite following the docs. I have regular Laravel job files which have `tries` defined and these work as intended. Any more suggestions?